# Windows 8.1 weird squares bug

Tags: windows, windows-8

My installtion of Windows 8.1 has some weird rendering bug:
[image]

I've tried deleting the FNTCACHE.DAT but that didn't helped.
I'm not sure when this was started, probably after some Windows Update.

Comment: What is your system locale and language?

Comment: English UI and English/Hebrew input

Comment: Try creating a new user profile and see if the issue occurs there as well.

Comment: I've created a new account, the problem still exits.

Answer (score 3):

Please download and install the Segoe UI font (and its variants) from [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1798). This should solve your problem. A common cause for those weird shapes is a missing font. And since Segoe UI is the default system font for newer Windows installations, there's a good chance that your system is missing this font (or one of its variants).

Since the icons/symbols are not appearing, I suspect that your system is missing one of the Segoe UI Symbol fonts. So make sure to download and install that variant, too.

Comment: Tried that, no change :[

Answer (score 0):

Try going to Control Panel --> Clock, Language, and Region --> Language, and see if, next to English, you see "Windows display language: Enabled", like so:

[image: Control Panel Language]

If not, click on **Options** to the right and then click on **Download and install language pack**.

Comment: It wasn't enabled at first(which is weird considering the fact that my UI is English and also my input. I've enabled English, restarted and still no luck.